# Splitting a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> Assume $f(x)$ is the probability density function (pdf) of a random variable $X\geq0$. Select a number $a$ between $0$ and $X$ uniformly and randomly and split the random variable to make two random variables $a$ and $X-a$. Find the joint pdf of $a$ and $X-a$.

**My effort:** we have to take the derivative of the following CDF with respect to $r$ and $s$:

$P(a\leq r,X-a\leq s)=P(X-a\leq s|a\leq r) P(a\leq r)$

I can calculate $P(a\leq r)$, but $P(X-a\leq s|a\leq r)$ is an ugly intergral.

Any idea? I thought it might be already in the literature, any good keywords to search for? Ideally, I want to do divide $X$ into $m$ random variables uniformly and find the joint pdf of the outcome (here $m=2$).

Comment: Are you assuming $\mathbb P(X>0)=1$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, actually $X\geq 0$. I edited the statement to reflect this.

Comment: For an arbitrary distribution I'm not sure you'll find a useful closed form. I computed
$$
f_A(a) = \int_0^\infty f_{A\mid X=x}(a)f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx = \int_a^\infty \frac ax f(x)\ \mathsf dx = a\mathbb E\left[\frac1X\mathsf 1_{\{X>a\}}\right].
$$

Comment: You already have the marginal pdf of $X$ and the conditional pdf of $A|X = x$ in hand, so equivalently you have the joint pdf of $(A, X)$ already. Starting from this maybe quicker.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks. But, I knew how to calculate this part. I need the second part.

Comment: The standard change of variable approach, based on the Jacobian, works perfectly. Renaming $a$ as $UX$ with $U$ uniform in $(0,1)$ and (supposedly) independent of $X$, one gets that the joint PDF of $Y=UX$ and $Z=(1-U)X$ is $$f_{Y,Z}(y,z)=\frac{f_X(y+z)}{y+z}\mathbf 1_{y>0,z>0}$$